# setState based on previous state (React)

Tags: reactjs, setstate

What is the best practice to set a new state based on the current state?

E.g.:

```
setCount(count + 1)
```

is it correct? What the risks?

Comment: This question is a bit different than the one referenced for closing. The one referenced is in relation to class components whereas this one is in relation to functional components and the hooks API.

Comment: @RossSheppard See the second linked question, which references hooks. The general issue is the same, though. Use the callback form when the state the running function currently has a reference to may be stale.

Comment: Yes, the newly linked answer makes more sense now and, of course, I would say the same. Thanks